# Recursive binary search - C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, recursion, binary-search

first post here so be gentle. I'm trying execute a recursive binary search. I have tried different variations of code to try to make the function work but i still doesnt.

Here's my code:

```
bool contained(int x, const int* pBegin, const int* pEnd){


    if(x==*pBegin) {                      //
        return pBegin;
    }
    int size = pEnd - pBegin;           //size of the array
    int mid= size/2;                    //the middle of the array
    int const* pMid = pBegin + mid;      //The address of the element in the middle of the array
    if(x>*pMid)                    //Condition that looks if x is to the left of the array
        return contained(x,pMid,pEnd);
    else if(x<*pMid)                    //Condition that looks if x is to the right of the array
        return contained(x,pBegin,pMid-1);
}

int main()
{
   cout << "Binary search, test: " << endl;
    int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9};
    int size = 9;
       for(int i=0; i<size; i+=1)
            arr[i] = i;
       bool find = containedInSortedarray(6, &arr[0], &arr[size]);
       cout << "Found " << find << endl;
}
```

For example here, when i execute my bool-contained function with a premade array and let it search for the value 6, it should eventually come to the conclusion that the element does not exist, yet my output says it does. Have i missed something in my code?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome! Did you try to debug your code? `return pBegin` while the function is returns `bool` is suspicious. Also, do you ever return `false`?

Comment: I havent, I'm not that familiar with debugging but maybe its worth to give it a go. I tried returning it to false if x was not found but it just ended up returing false then...

Comment: because you are overwriting the array content with that loop? arr[i] = i , hence 6 actually exists.

Comment: What do you think this code is doing `for(int i=0; i<size; i+=1) arr[i] = i;`? A debugger would have found this error almost immediately. You should familiarize yourself with how to debug your own code.

Comment: Fair point. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Consider what happens in `contains()` if `x` is exactly equal to `*pMid`  (which can potentially happen if any of the values in the array are duplicated).   The `if` and the `else if` clauses are both false, so the function "falls off the end" - which causes undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Quimby, debugging recursive functions can be a nightmare!

Comment: @TonyK Sure, but not debugging is not exactly a good idea either. At least the debugger is not jumping too much from function to function ;)

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of issues with your code:

1. You never return `false`.
2. You return `pBegin` which is not a bool, (sadly in your case) it is implicitly convertible to one, but not in the way you want it too. Turn on your compiler warnings all the way up - `-Wextra -Wall -pedantic -Werror` should be the bare minimum, especially if you are a beginner.
3. Be precise about the interval your function searches in. `func(x,a,b)` - does it include `b`? Based on `contained(x,pBegin,pMid-1);` it seems it does, but in the case of `containedInSortedarray(6, &arr[0], &arr[size]);` hopefully not.
4. Dereferencing `&arr[size]` is UB.
5. What is the purpose of the for loop in main?
6. Having the size detached from the array is a disaster waiting to happen. At least use `sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])`. Better yet, use `std::array` or a `std::vector`.

I would suggest searching `[a,b)` because it can be easily be divided into `[a,mid)`, `[mid,end)`. That way your `mid` computation is already correct. You can then call it like `containedInSortedarray(x,arr,arr+arr_size)`

The base condition should catch the arrays of size 0 and 1 - both can be trivially tested for presence of `x`.

Comment: concerning the disaster, OP isnt waiting anymore, it is right there: `for(int i=0; i<size; i+=1) arr[i] = i;` actual size of `arr` is `8` (`size-1`)

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Good catch, did not notice that. At least I was right :D